# Slider Menu Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ***

error while following this tutorial. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

I am try to make slider menu...I have done all the things correctly but I don't understand why I am getting this error.

DashboardViewController.h

```
@interface DashboardViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *menuButton;   

@end
```

DashboardViewController.m

```
[_menuButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: you have not post the full error. please paste it here again

Comment: can you share code with me via dropbox or etc

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure you have imported the SWRevealViewController in DashboardViewController.

2) Make sure you have given correct identifiers to the segues and is of class SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController.

3) Make sure your button is connected to its IBOutlet.

4) Then in DashboardViewController.m :

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [_menuButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector( revealToggle: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method but revealViewController return back with "nil" and because of this it is not entering in if block. Why I am getting this "nil"

Comment: for first view this is working. but i have to add SWRevealViewController to my this screen..and after debugging the parent class is returning nil value?

Comment: @KimSharma - Which is your first view? You need to provide more code and explanation.